# MongoDB Scheduled Trigger Save Error -- What to Return?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, triggers, return

This problem is very annoying. So, I am making a **scheduled trigger** run every 24 hours. It simply gets items from one collection does some data processing then appends information to another collection. **The functioning code works** even when the function runs. But it will not let me save because there are "runtime" errors? Even though it was executed perfectly and returned.

Console Error

```
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('{"$undefined":true}')
```

I suppose this has something to do with returning. but when I return `null` I get this:

```
> result: 
null
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('null')
```

when trying to save I get this at the top of the page:

```
runtime error during function validation
```

Function Code:

```
exports = async function() {
  const usersCol = context.services.get("SchoologyDashCluster").db("SchoologyDashApp").collection("users");
  const gradesCol = context.services.get("SchoologyDashCluster").db("SchoologyDashApp").collection("grades");
  var usersCusor = await usersCol.find( ).toArray();
  var gradesCusor = await gradesCol.find( ).toArray();
  let insert = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < usersCusor.length; i++) {
    var user = usersCusor[i];

    var userSavedGrades = gradesCusor[i].grades
    var currentGrades = await getGrades(user.schoologyUID, user.consumerKey, user.secretKey);
    
    var lastGraded = NaN;
    let index = gradesCusor[i].grades.length - 1;
    
    while (true) {
      if (gradesCusor[i].grades[index].changed == 1) {
        lastGraded = index;
        break
      }
      index = index - 1;
    }
    console.log(lastGraded)
    if (userSavedGrades[lastGraded].grades.ga == currentGrades.ga){
      currentGrades = { changed : 0, time: new Date().getTime()};
    } else {
      currentGrades = {changed : 1, grades: currentGrades, time : new Date().getTime()};
    }
    
    
    gradesCol.updateOne(
      {"user" : user._id},
      {"$push" : {"grades" : currentGrades}}
    )
  }
  // return usersCol.find( );
  
  
  return null;
};
```

Comment: I believe that the solution is to use mongo's built-in HTTP module for a request. Instead of using the HTTP module in node. the request is made in that get grades function. I will post the answer if it works...

Comment: that did not work... niether did somthing as simple as this `exports = function(consumerKey, secretKey, _url) {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("hello");
  });
  p.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  })
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple and now I feel ignorant. Instinctual I put the module imports at the top of the document. However this is incorrect and they need to be placed in the exports function, like so:

```
exports = function (x,y,z) {
 const http = context.http;
 return;
}
```